# nth child overriding first child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have 3 styles I need in a repeating design without changing the classes on the HTML side. I've been trying to accomplish this with nth-child selectors. The first class needs to have a different background image than the even and odd classes. My odd class keeps keeps overriding my first child class. I tried changing it to nth-child(2n+3), but no luck either. 
How can I get my first child div to keep its background image?

```
/* Even Featured */

.home-feature-container:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color:#393939;
    padding-bottom: 20px;    
}    

.home-feature-container:nth-child(even) .home-featured-left
{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url('/images/featured-top-gray.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    background-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}    

.home-feature-container:nth-child(even) .home-featured-right
{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url('/images/featured-top-spacer-gray.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    background-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}    

/* Odd Featured */

.home-feature-container:nth-child(2n+3)
{
    background-color:#252424;
    padding-bottom: 20px;    
}    

.home-feature-container:nth-child(2n+3) .home-featured-left
{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url('/images/featured-top-black.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    background-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}    

.home-feature-container:nth-child(2n+3) .home-featured-right
{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url('/images/featured-top-spacer-black.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    background-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}  

/* First Featured */

.home-feature-container:first-child 
{
    background-color:#252424;
    padding-bottom: 20px;    
}    

.home-feature-container:first-child  .home-featured-left
{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url('/images/featured-top-first.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    background-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}    

.home-feature-container:first-child  .home-featured-right
{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url('/images/featured-top-spacer-first.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    background-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

And the HTML

```
    <div class="div_wrapper home-feature-container">
        <div class="home-featured-left">
            <div class="home-featured-left-content">
            <h3 class="title">Feature</h3>
            <h3>Sed tincidunt purus</h3>
            <div class="home-featured-copy">Eu lectus varius auctor. Integer et elit bibendum, fermentum velit a, aliquam est. Donec varius arcu rutrum lorem ultrices, et tristique leo pretium. Nam porttitor lacinia nunc, sit amet maximus justo placerat ac. Curabitur ut tellus sed nisi faucibus.
            </div>
            </div>
        </div><div class="home-featured-right">
            <div class="home-featured-right-content"><img src="/images/featured-image-home.jpg" class="home-featured-image" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell what the problem is from that code; you're targeting `.home-feature-container:first-child  .home-featured-right` but without seeing more of the HTML, it's not clear if that `.home-feature-container` is in fact a `first-child`. Can you create a runnable snippet or codepen with the full code, and/or attach an image of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think nth child don't work on `<div>`. It works on lists like `<li>`.

Comment: A reduced test case shows the `:first-child` can override a preceding `:nth-child` with no problem, so I suspect the issue lies elsewhere. For starters, you have a lot of confusing and unnecessary repetition of styles; if you simplify those you might uncover your issue.

Comment: @Jozi Bashaj nth-child() indeed works on divs. AFAIK it works on any element.

Comment: As usual, if you find one rule overriding another, change the specificity of one or the other. [Here's a resource that takes a fun look at specificity](http://cssspecificity.com/). [And here's a more sober look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: nth selectors ignore class, when using them you should pay attention to siblings and ancestors. If you use `nth-child`, all siblings will be counted but it's the tagName that gets styled. `nth-of-type` will skip unmatched tagNames and style and count only sibling tagNames that match the selector. Your layout is all nested there are at the most maybe 2 siblings at any given level. nth selectors are probably not good for your site.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the question properly, the selectors are not selecting anything in your html, you need to select the children of the home-feature-container div.

I used the wildcard (*) for simplicity, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s3e7wauu/)

**Your HTML:**

```
<div class="div_wrapper home-feature-container">
  <div class="home-featured-left">
    <div class="home-featured-left-content">
      <h3 class="title">Feature</h3>
      <h3>Sed tincidunt purus</h3>
      <div class="home-featured-copy">Eu lectus varius auctor. Integer et elit bibendum, fermentum velit a, aliquam est. Donec varius arcu rutrum lorem ultrices, et tristique leo pretium. Nam porttitor lacinia nunc, sit amet maximus justo placerat ac. Curabitur ut tellus sed nisi faucibus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="home-featured-right">
  <div class="home-featured-right-content"><img src="/images/featured-image-home.jpg" class="home-featured-image" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Modified CSS:**

```
/* Even Featured */

.home-feature-container *:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color:#393939;
    padding-bottom: 20px;    
}    

.home-feature-container *:nth-child(even) .home-featured-left
{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url('/images/featured-top-gray.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    background-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}    

.home-feature-container *:nth-child(even) .home-featured-right
{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url('/images/featured-top-spacer-gray.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    background-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}    

/* Odd Featured */

.home-feature-container *:nth-child(2n+3)
{
    background-color:#252424;
    padding-bottom: 20px;    
}
```